# Is there a way to nudge an observable value in MobX?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

So, I have a store that contains Auth information in a React app. The auth is derived from a JWT token. The store has an `@observable` value called `loggedIn` that checks if the auth store even has a token and if that token has not already expired, kind of like the following:

```
class AuthStore {
  @observable token = cookies('api_token');
  @computed get loggedIn() {
    if (!this.token) {
      return false;
    }
    return jwt_expires_in(this.token) > 60;
  }
}
```

MobX depends on actions to know when to propagate state change around an application, but the result of `loggedIn()` changes not because of user interaction, but simply the passing of time.

So, what I am wondering is how I get this value to propogate without any user interaction, how to "nudge" it on a given interval so that the application can properly respond to expiring authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you simply do the following?

`class AuthStore {
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => this.token = null, calc-time-to-expire + 60*1000)
  }
}`

Otherwise, store the expires time in a separate value, and update it at certain intervals. 
e.g. `@observable expires_in = 0`, and `setInterval(() => this.expiresIn = token ? 0 : jwt_expires(token), 1000)`